# MySQL Syntax error

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this code?

```
FROM product_tag, ps_product_tags_all
LEFT JOIN users ON
users.id = product_tag.lang
LEFT JOIN images ON
images.id = ps_product_tags_all.lang
```

Error:

```
Unknown column 'product_tag.lang' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: Does lang actually exist in the product_tag table ;-)

Comment: please post the table structure and whole query then.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing implicit and explicit joins and joining in the wrong order. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ps_product_tags_all
LEFT JOIN images ON
images.id = ps_product_tags_all.lang, product_tag
LEFT JOIN users ON
users.id = product_tag.lang
WHERE ...
```

Remember that explicit JOIN has higher precedence than the implicit join from using comma. To avoid this error I would recommend that you always use explicit joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM ps_product_tags_all
LEFT JOIN images ON images.id = ps_product_tags_all.lang
LEFT JOIN product_tag ON ...
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = product_tag.lang
```

Comment: good to know, i've always joined without that info and never had such problem. ;]

Answer (score 2):

This is not syntax error, but structure error - you don't have "lang" column in "product_tag" table.

Comment: This probably isn't the reason why the query is failing.