# where {table1.field} *= {table2.field} syntax

Tags: sql, sybase

I have just picked up an SQL statement that was written by someone a couple of weeks ago (nobody seems to know who).

As part of the statement, in the `WHERE` clause, they have something like: `{table1.field} *= {table2.samefield}`.

What exactly is going on here? I assume some sort of join, but what join and why and, generically, why would someone put this in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Similar to Programming Language A*=B.  ---> A=A*B;

Comment: @Senthil Prabhu: Worth a thought but it's actually a left outer join operator in Sybase (non-ANSI). Same as how Oracle has its proprietary (+) annotation to it's join operator. Use of ANSI-standard SQL would be a cross-DBMS recommendation.

Comment: @Ben: If u looking with regards of ANSI have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684259/sql-joins-future-of-the-sql-ansi-standard-where-vs-join

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be Sybase's outer join annotation:

> Include in the results all the rows from the first table, not just the ones where the joined columns match.

See:
[Sybase docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug145.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It's the SyBase join operator equivalent to a more conventional `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or more commonly, `LEFT JOIN`.

Refer:  [SyBooks Online - The `WHERE` clause](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug21.htm)

> *=
>
> Include in the results all the rows from the first table, not just
>   the ones where the joined columns match.

As opposed to the `=*` which is a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` (or more commonly `RIGHT JOIN`).